# Need to copy a file into common folder location path for each user in one go

Tags: command-line, command-line-interface

I have a file (named test.txt) that is currently only located on the Windows desktop for my user account. I need to copy this file to the same directory in each user account on this computer, such as:

`C:\Users\MR.A\AppData\Roaming\Settings\test.txt`
`C:\Users\MR.B\AppData\Roaming\Settings\test.txt`
`C:\Users\MR.C\AppData\Roaming\Settings\test.txt`

Within each user account, the path to the new location would be the same. How would I do this using the command line?

Comment: Changed the question to a less user-specific issue so that a general answer could apply

Comment: Windows won't let you write to the users folders for other users. How do you propose to get past that restriction? Even as an admin user, you can't just arbitrarily access user folders that don't belong to you; you have to confirm via UAC that you want to take ownership of the folder. If you really need to put a file in each user's folder, do it properly via Group Policy.

Comment: Take the question more generic. If its any other folder like 'D:\folder\MR.A\AppData\Roaming\Settings\test.txt' 'D:\folder\MR.B\AppData\Roaming\Settings\test.txt' 'D:\folder\MR.C\AppData\Roaming\Settings\test.txt'